# install rvm without write permissions to /usr/local

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install `rvm` for my user on a development server.  The problem is I don't have write permissions to `/usr/local`, so I get this:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
mktemp: failed to create file via template `/usr/local/rvm/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX': Permission denied
```

how can I get around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417269/install-rvm-into-the-current-user-home-directory -- not helpful?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I installed it on my user folder: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --user-install --auto --path /home/your_user/.rvm`.

Also note that the [rvm installation script](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) 
is pretty much self-explainatory

Answer (score -2):

Use `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash` instead of `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`
this will help you.

Comment: this will install RVM for *all* users, not for his or her user